# Формирование подписи. Интеркасса

Tags: python, django

Настраиваю оплату на сайте через интеркассу. Интеркасса после удачной оплаты пользователем, отправляет на сервер оповещение о платеже.
Подпись формируется путём склеивания всех полей запроса и вклеивания в конец секретного ключа, с последующей кодировкой в **md5** или **sha256** в байт-массив.
Форма:

```
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_am" value="1.00">
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_act" value="process">
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_co_id" value="571624f33d1eafb1528b456b">
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_co_prs_id" value="307447812424">
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_co_rfn" value="0.94">
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_cur" value="RUB">
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_desc" value="Оплата товара">
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_inv_crt" value="2013-03-17 17:35:33">
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_inv_id" value="5632156">
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_inv_prc" value="2013-03-17 17:36:13">
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_inv_st" value="success">
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_pm_no" value="70">
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_ps_price" value="20">
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_pw_via" value="yandex">
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_trn_id" value="14533">
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_sign" value="oVAOevI3mWrcvrjB4j/ySg==">
```

```
variables = "%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s" % (
                        form.cleaned_data['ik_am'],
                        form.cleaned_data['ik_act'],
                        form.cleaned_data['ik_co_id'],
                        form.cleaned_data['ik_co_prs_id'],
                        form.cleaned_data['ik_co_rfn'],
                        form.cleaned_data['ik_cur'],
                        form.cleaned_data['ik_desc'],
                        form.cleaned_data['ik_inv_crt'],
                        form.cleaned_data['ik_inv_id'],
                        form.cleaned_data['ik_inv_prc'],
                        form.cleaned_data['ik_inv_st'],
                        form.cleaned_data['ik_pm_no'],
                        form.cleaned_data['ik_ps_price'],
                        form.cleaned_data['ik_pw_via'],
                        form.cleaned_data['ik_trn_id']
                        )
```

Для склеивания я использую `hash_key = md5(variables.encode('utf-8')).digest()` для хеширования. Но получаю ошибку:

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 0: ordinal not in
>   range(128)

Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Вопрос стоит дополнить, тогда на него скорее будет ответ. Хорошо бы добавить пример переменных –  `form.cleaned_data` и `variables`. Сам код, который всё это проворачивает, тоже не помешал бы.

Answer (score 1):

Так как в начале кода вы не используете префикс `u` перед двойными кавычками и у вас возникла эта ошибка значит вы используете Python2. Вам его нужно обязательно указать чтобы Python понял что вы собираете unicode-строку. Данный вами код написан немного неоптимально и я бы переписал вот-так:

```
keys = 'am,act,co_id,co_prs_id,co_rfn,cur,desc,inv_crt,'\
       'inv_id,inv_prc,inv_st,pm_no,ps_price,pw_via,trn_id'
variables = u':'.join(unicode(form.cleaned_data['ik_'+k]) for k in keys.split(','))
hash_key = md5(variables.encode('utf-8')).digest()
```